# Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Stopwatch' and 'int'

Tags: android, xamarin

```
Stopwatch startTime1=null;
TimeSpan secondsToFormat;
startTime1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
startTime1.Stop();
secondsToFormat = secondsToFormat+ startTime1.Elapsed;

if (ClicksCount == 2)
{
     secondsToFormat = startTime1 / 2;
     AverageMsCount.Text = secondsToFormat.ToString();
     TriesCount.Text = "2";                 
}
```

Hello guys,I hope you are having a good day today.So, startTime1 is a rection time and I'm trying to get average reaction time but I can't divide startTime1 by 2 after trying i get error like in title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StopWatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) is an object.  If you refer to its documentation, it contains an `Elapsed` property that is a `TimeSpan`.  [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx), in turn, contains a `TotalSeconds` property that is a `double`;

var avg = startTime1.Elapsed.TotalSeconds / 2;

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you cant divide a Stopwatch object, you can use the `obj.ElapsedMilliseconds / 2` as an example.